# Execute Serverless SQL Pool external table / Views from Synapse notebook using Python

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I have a Serverless SQL pool which contains external tables/Views write against ADLS Gen2 parquet files.

I want to call external table / views from synapse  notebook using python.

FYI. Server less SQL Pool  Identity is Azure Active directory.

Can you please let me know how can achieve this.

```
Using Scala it is working the below code. Need same in the python using active directory authentication.

// Define connection:
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")

val hostname = "demo-da-synapse-test-ondemand.sql.azuresynapse.net"
val port = 1433
val database = "Demo" // If needed, change the database 
val jdbcUrl = s"jdbc:sqlserver://${hostname}:${port};database=${database}"

// Define connection properties:
import java.util.Properties

val props = new Properties()
props.put("user", "testuser")
props.put("password", "test202XXX!")

// Assign driver to connection:
val driverClass = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
props.setProperty("Driver", driverClass)

val tsqlQuery ="select top 100 * from  [demo].[tblEmp]"

val df = spark.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl, s"(${tsqlQuery}) res", props)

df.show(10)
```

Thank you,
Sunny

Answer (score 0):

To connect Serverless SQL pool with Synapse python notebook with Azure AD authentication. you need to install ADAL4j library on your spark pool.

**You can download ADAL4j library from [here](https://jar-download.com/artifact-search/adal4j)**

After downloading it extract and upload it in workspace

> Goto Manage >> Workspace packages >> Upload >>select jar files you downloaded.

[image]

Then add this package in your spark pool as below.

> Go to Manage >> Apache Spark pool >> 3 dots beside  saprk pool name >> packages.

[image]

Click on select from workspace packages:

[image]

select all packages and click apply the changes.

[image]

Then try below code in your synapse notebook:

```py
jdbcHostname = "servername-ondemand.sql.azuresynapse.net"
jdbcDatabase = "dbname"
jdbcPort = "1433"
username = "Adusername"
password = "AD password"
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.sql.azuresynapse.net;loginTimeout=30;authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase)
connectionProperties = {
"user" : username,
"password" : password,
"driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
}
pushdown_query = "select * from ext1"
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=pushdown_query, properties=connectionProperties)
display(df)
```

If you receive any authentication error error-code ***Make sure you disable Security Defaults by visiting > Azure Active Directory > Security > Security Defaults > Disable***

If the error persists after disabling Security Defaults, ***Check if there's an MFA or any Conditional Access Policy applied to the user by visiting > Azure Active Directory > Security > Conditional Access > Remove Policy or exclude the user from the Policy.***

Comment: Thanks Pratik, I did all the steps. i am getting  the below error.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3867.jdbc.
: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Failed to load ADAL4J Java library for performing ActiveDirectoryPassword authentication.
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getFedAuthToken(SQLServerConnection.java:4440)